# Change column class based on other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a data frame and I am trying to convert class of each variable of dt based on col_type.

Find example below for more detail.

```
> dt
  id <- c(1,2,3,4)
   a <- c(1,4,5,6)
   b <- as.character(c(0,1,1,4))
   c <- as.character(c(0,1,1,0))
   d <- c(0,1,1,0)
  dt <- data.frame(id,a,b,c,d, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> str(dt)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id: num  1 2 3 4
 $ a : num  1 4 5 6
 $ b : chr  "0" "1" "1" "4"
 $ c : chr  "0" "1" "1" "0"
 $ d : num  0 1 1 0
```

Now, I am trying to convert class of each column based on below data frame.

```
> var  
  var <- c("id","a","b","c","d")
  type <- c("character","numeric","numeric","integer","character")
  col_type <- data.frame(var,type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> col_type
  var      type
1  id character
2   a   numeric
3   b   numeric
4   c   integer
5   d character
```

I want to convert id to class mention in col_type data frame and so on for all other columns.

**My Attempts:**

```
setDT(dt)
for(i in 1:ncol(dt)){
  if(colnames(dt)[i]%in%col_type$var){
    a <- col_type[col_type$var==paste0(intersect(colnames(dt)[i],col_type$var)),]
    dt[,col_type$var[i]:=eval(parse(text = paste0("as.",col_type$type[i],"(",col_type$var[i],")")))]
  }
  
}
```

**Note-** My solution works but it is really slow and I am wondering if I can do it more efficiently and cleanly.

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the data in with the `colClasses` argument derived from the `col_type` table:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(col_type)

res = capture.output(fwrite(dt)) %>% paste(collapse="\n") %>% 
  fread(colClasses = col_type[, setNames(type, var)])

str(res)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ a : num  1 4 5 6
 $ b : num  0 1 1 4
 $ c : int  0 1 1 0
 $ d : chr  "0" "1" "1" "0"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

If you can do this when the data is read in initially, it simplifies to...

```
 res = fread("file.csv", colClasses = col_type[, setNames(type, var)])
```

It's straightforward to do all of this without data.table.

---

If somehow the data is never read into R (received as RDS?), there's:

```
setDT(dt)
res = dt[, Map(as, .SD, col_type$type), .SDcols=col_type$var]

str(res)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ a : num  1 4 5 6
 $ b : num  0 1 1 4
 $ c : int  0 1 1 0
 $ d : chr  "0" "1" "1" "0"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

See `showMethods("coerce")` *as* some conversions might fail, e.g.: `as(letters[1:3], "factor")`

Comment: I know about this colClasses parameter but I can't write and read it. My data size is really large and its not feasible.

Comment: any other alternative to make my solution efficient?

Comment: @Rushabh You only have the data in R stored with the wrong column classes; not on disk prior to reading into R? Not terribly efficient, but you can use the `?as` function for conversion, at least to the classes you've identified. It's pretty weak, though, eg `as("2018-01-01", "Date")` fails. Anyway, I'll edit it in.

Comment: your map solution is working but I am get warning "In asMethod(object) : NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: @Rushabh I guess the warning is just there for you to recognize cases like `as.numeric(c(1, 2, "zip"))` since the last element cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: alright got it. I really appreciate your help. learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `get()` inside `Map` which can be used to retrieve a function from its string literal using `as.*` functions. Then bind list of vectors into a dataframe.

```
vec_list <- Map(function(v, t) get(paste0("as.", t))(dt[[v]]), col_type$var, col_type$type)

dt_new <- data.frame(vec_list, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(dt_new)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ id: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
# $ a : num  1 4 5 6
# $ b : num  0 1 1 4
# $ c : int  0 1 1 0
# $ d : chr  "0" "1" "1" "0"
```

Possibly wrap `get()` in `tryCatch` if conversions can potentially fail.